# Как сделать карусель миниатюр на jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Делаю галерею с миниатюрами

```js
$(".show-image").click(function() {
    event.preventDefault();
    var mainImage = $(this).index(); 
    $('.images img').removeClass('active');
    $('.images img').eq(mainImage).addClass('active'); 
});
```

```css
.container {display: flex;}
.images img {display: none; margin-right: 10px;}
.images .active {display: block}
.thumbs { position: relative; display: flex; flex-direction: column; flex-wrap: wrap;  width: 80px; height: 105px; overflow: hidden; }
.thumbs a { display: inline-block; margin-right: 10px; }
.prev, .next {position: absolute; top: 40px; }
.next {position: absolute; right: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="images">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150?text=1" class="active"/>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150?text=2" />
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150?text=3" />
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150?text=4" />
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150?text=5" />
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150?text=6" />
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150?text=7" />
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150?text=8" />  
  </div>
  <div class="thumbs">
    <a href="http://placehold.it/350x150?text=1" class="show-image"><img src="http://placehold.it/30x30?text=1"></a>
    <a href="http://placehold.it/350x150?text=2" class="show-image"><img src="http://placehold.it/30x30?text=2"></a>
    <a href="http://placehold.it/350x150?text=3" class="show-image"><img src="http://placehold.it/30x30?text=3"></a>
    <a href="http://placehold.it/350x150?text=4" class="show-image"><img src="http://placehold.it/30x30?text=4"></a>
    <a href="http://placehold.it/350x150?text=4" class="show-image"><img src="http://placehold.it/30x30?text=5"></a>
    <a href="http://placehold.it/350x150?text=4" class="show-image"><img src="http://placehold.it/30x30?text=6"></a>
    <a href="http://placehold.it/350x150?text=4" class="show-image"><img src="http://placehold.it/30x30?text=7"></a>
    <a href="http://placehold.it/350x150?text=4" class="show-image"><img src="http://placehold.it/30x30?text=8"></a> 
    <button class="prev"> < </button>
    <button class="next"> > </button>
</div>
```

По умолчанию выводятся 6 миниатюр, остальные будут показываться при скролле влево. Как мне теперь сделать карусель миниатюр? Подключать сторонние плагины не хочу.

Comment: Если мой ответ Вам помог, то обозначьте его, пожалуйста, как принятый, кликнув на `v` под счетчиком голосов ответа

Answer (score 0):

Рекомендую использовать Slick.js.

Но если хотите сделать свой собственный "велосипед", то клонируете `n-1` миниатюр с конца и располагаете перед первой миниатюрой. И столько же миниатюр с начала - после последней. `n` - это количество видимых миниатюр - 6 в Вашем случае.

При прокрутке влево-вправо переключаете видимость миниатюр на -1/+1. При достижении начала/конца набора, включающего клоны - переключаетесь на конец/начало оригинального набора.